# gsub - adding whitespace before/after & character

Tags: regex, r, gsub

first post on stackoverflow and hopefully the first of many.

I am cleaning up a dataset containing a list of authors in one of its columns. When there are multiple authors, these are separated by ampersands eg. Smith & Banks. However, the spacing is not always consistent eg. Smith& Banks, Smith &Banks.

To solve the issue, I have tried:

```
     gsub('\\S&','\\S &', dataset[,author.col])
```

This gives Smith& Banks -> SmitS & Banks. How can I get -> Smith & Banks?

Comment: Do you have cases where there is for example `Smith &&Banks`, i.e. multiple ampersands between the same authors?

Comment: I don't have those cases and my only delimiter between different names is an ampersand.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `gsub` approach:

```
# some test cases
authors <- c("Smith& Banks", "Smith   &Banks", "Smith&Banks", "Smith & Banks")
gsub("\\s*&\\s*", " & ", authors)
#[1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks"
```

---

Some more test cases (more than 2 authors, single authors):

```
authors <- c("Smith& Banks", "Smith   &Banks &Nash", "Smith&Banks", "Smith & Banks", "Smith")
gsub("\\s*&\\s*", " & ", authors)
#[1] "Smith & Banks"        "Smith & Banks & Nash" "Smith & Banks"        "Smith & Banks"        "Smith"
```

As OP noted in the comments to their question, multiple ampersands between two authors do not occur in the data.

Comment: Your regex might have unintended consequences in the event that a name has more than one ambersand.

Comment: Depends what you define as "a name". Cases of multiple ampersands between the same names in a string (like `Smith &&Banks`) are problematic - I agree, but I didn't understand the question as such - whereas multiple ampersands between different names in a vector element (like `"Smith   &Banks & Nash"`) do not cause any problems

Comment: And of course, some of the other answer also don't handle multiple ampersands correctly - but I would first expect the OP to clarify whether that can happen

Comment: This works for me, thanks. Have multiple ampersands in many rows but no more than one delimiting two names.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which makes two calls to `gsub`:

```
dataset[,author.col] <- gsub('([^\\s])&','\\1\\s&', dataset[,author.col])
dataset[,author.col] <- gsub('&([^\\s])','&\\s\\1', dataset[,author.col])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using only `sub`

```
sub("\\b(?=&)|(?<=&)\\b", " ",  v1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks"
```

---

Using data with more combinations.  In the above, I only considered the options showed in the OP's post.

```
 gsub("\\s*(?=&)|(?<=&)\\s*", " ", data, perl = TRUE)
 #[1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks"

 gsub("\\s*&+|\\&+\\s*", " & ", data1)
 #[1] "Smith &  Banks" "Smith & Banks"  "Smith & Banks"  
 #[4]"Smith & Banks"  "Smith & Banks"  "Smith &  Banks" "Smith & Banks"
```

Or with `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(data1, "\\s*&+\\s*"), paste, collapse = " & ")
#[1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" 
#[5] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks"
```

In essence, the `strsplit` method was found to be better if there are many patterns.

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Smith& Banks", "Smith &Banks")
data = c("Smith& Banks", "Smith &Banks", "Smith & Banks", 
     "Smith &     Banks", "Smith&Banks")
data1 <- c(v1, "Smith&& Banks", "Smith && Banks", "Smith&&Banks")
```

Answer (score 2):

An overkill way using `stringi`:

```
v <- c("Smith & Banks", "Smith& Banks", "Smith &Banks", "Smith&Banks", "Smith Banks")

library(stringi)
#create an index of entries containing "&"
indx <- grepl("&", v)
#subset "v" using that index
amp  <- v[indx]
#perform the transformation on that subset and combine the result with the rest of "v"
c(sapply(stri_extract_all_words(amp), 
         function(x) { paste0(x, collapse = " & ") }), v[!indx])
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith Banks"
```

Comment: This solution will add `&` where they were not present: `"Smith Banks"` -> `"Smith & Banks"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right. Just re-read the question and noticed there also were non amp. words.

Comment: That is a nice option, I thought you deleted it, so I was using a similar one with strsplit.

Comment: @akrun I initially did following Wiktor comment but ended up tweaking it. Nice one with `strsplit`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = c("Smith& Banks", "Smith &Banks", "Smith & Banks", 
         "Smith &     Banks", "Smith&Banks")

# Take the 0 or more spaces before and after the ampersand, replace that by " & ""
gsub("[ ]*&[ ]*", " & ", data) 
# [1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this:

```
gsub("([^& ]+)\\W+([^&]+)","\\1 & \\2",authors)
[1] "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks" "Smith & Banks"
```